# Difference between やつ and こと in those sentences 不幸な事故ということだな and 不幸な事故というやつだな

Tags: grammar

Difference between やつ and こと in those sentences

> 不幸な事故ということだな

and

> 不幸な事故というやつだな

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference is that 「やつ」 makes it sound more casual and colloquial, if not slangy, than 「こと」.

The two sentences mean the exact same.

> "That is to say it is an unfortunate accident."